PostgreSQL - Shared road sections between two counties: how to dynamically show left and right county names according to zip code
I have table "network" containing data on a road network spread across several contiguous counties.
Many road sections are shared between two counties (ie. left side belongs to county A and right side belongs to county B).
So the table has two columns : L_zipcode and R_zipcode (you guessed why) and each row is a road section.
I also have table "counties" with columns zipcode and county_name
As properties of the road sections might be modified (for real life reasons), sections' L_zipcode and R_zipcode data might also change.
So my goal is to create two generated columns in the "network" table (or maybe a view?) named L_county and R_county. That way, everytime L_zipcode or R_zipcode change, L_county and R_county would change accordingly.
Any idea how to get there?

There's a many-to-many relationship between US counties and US zipcodes, and road segments could cross county or zipcode lines, so this might not be a trivial exercise.
